# Turning debug log on/off Weblogic Server

Tags: linux, weblogic12c

How do i turn off debug logging in Weblogic 12c? I see a weblogic.log file in /tmp folder on my Linux server which is of around 3gb already.
I searched for the debug.properties file but could not find it. Please help.

Comment: check the below link.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/task_runtimes/DefineDebugSettings.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AdminServer and check your ManagedServers -> Debug tab to see which debug flags are enabled.

You can disable it, save and activate your changes. After that check your logs to see if it works.